# Accessing core data through hierarchy relationships

Tags: xcode, core-data

My core data model has a relationship of one-to-many between an entity `Athlete` and `Event` and from `Event` to `Stats` I have a one-to-one relationship. Basically, my model looks like `Athlete <<----->Events<------->Stats` So, one athlete can have an unknown amount of events and within those events, the athlete can have one set of stats for each event. My question is how would I access the specific stats for the certain event within the certain athlete. My code works fine with adding the athletes and then making certain events for each athlete, but I'm having trouble accessing the objects in `Stats` that correlate to the specific event within the specific athlete. How would I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, your data model is not correct. What you describe in your text should look like this (I am also removing the confusing plural forms of your entities):

```
Athlete (stats)  <---------->> (athlete) Stats
Stats   (event)  <<----------> (stats)   Event
```

The key to understand here is that the Stats is some kind of "join table" that joins athletes with events and stores the "byproduct" of this relationship. If you did not want to store any additional data (like stats), the many-to-many relationship you propose would be appropriate.

To get all athletes from an event:

```
[event.stats valueForKeyPath:@"athlete"]
```

To get all events an athlete participated in:

```
[athlete.stats valueForKeyPath:@"event"];
```

To get the stats for an athlete for a particular event:

```
[[athlete.stats filteredSetUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"event = %@", event]] anyObject];
```